psutil returns 0.0 for process.create_time()
I'm struggling to understand this block of code:
import psutil
import time

def main():

    process_dict = {}
    psutil.process_iter.cache_clear()
    processes = psutil.process_iter()

    for process in processes:
        duration = time.time() - process.create_time()
        if process.name() not in process_dict.keys(): # Find the longest running process for each application
            process_dict[process.name()] = duration
        elif process.name() in process_dict.keys() and duration > process_dict[process.name()]:
            process_dict[process.name()] = duration
        print(f'{process.name()} : {process.create_time()}')

The output seems to be only partially correct:
System Idle Process : 0.0
System : 0.0
 : 1722366605.6514304
Registry : 1722366605.7470324
WidgetService.exe : 1722646907.9835372
MoUsoCoreWorker.exe : 1722366742.625491
smss.exe : 1722366607.7051022
csrss.exe : 1722366616.5462563
svchost.exe : 1722366619.7795236
...


Why is the create_time() for the first 2 processes 0.0? That would mean they've been running for 54 years which clearly isn't correct.
Why is there an empty string for the third process? What is this mysterious process with no name?
I want to find how long each application on my computer has been running, yet when I convert duration into hours and minutes for some processes, they're quite lengthy (e.g. 82 hours) which can't be correct as I shut down my laptop at the end of each day so all processes should be less than 24 hours. Why does this happen?


I guess the OS doesn't store the create time for these special  system processes.

When did you run this? All those create times are on July 30.

For the blank process name, get its process ID and look for it with some other tool. It's probably another special system process.

@Barmar I ran this yesterday on August 3
